# ASP.NET MVC Scripting in js files

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I still find myself having to declare global variables in my .aspx files (the project was started before razor).  For example I have to declare global javascript variables like this in my .aspx files:

```
var getDistributionListUrl = '<%= Url.Action("GetDistributionList", "PublicDocument") %>';
```

I can then reference this variable in my .js files.

Is there a better way?

Comment: No need to apologize for using WebForms, there are still plenty of reasons to use it over Razor.

Answer (score 3):

> Is there a better way?

There is nothing wrong with this.

Personally I use HTML5 data-* attributes on some DOM elements that I am manipulating later in my scripts. For example:

```
<div id="foo" data-url="<%= Url.Action("GetDistributionList", "PublicDocument") %>">
    Hello
</div>
```

and then in my js:

```
$('#foo').click(function() {
    var url = $(this).data('url');
    ...
});
```

But in 99.99% of the cases those urls are associated with either `<form>` elements or link hrefs so in my javascript I simply retrieve and use this value when I need to do some progressive enhancement on the given DOM element (like unobtrusively AJAXifying forms or anchors).